# How Can I Find an Item By Index In My Firebase Database List?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get an item by its index position, but for some reason doing `firebaseRef.somelist[myindexposition]` won't work and it returns an unindefined. Please help me with getting my item from the list by its index.

For example I need to find user #3 in the /users reference.

I would do it like this:

```
var user3 = myfirebaseref.users[2];
console.log(user3);
```

result:

```
"unindefined"
```

Why does it not show me the user 3 and instead it shows me unindefined?

When I do it like this, it works:

```
var user3 = myfirebaseref.users.user3name;
console.log(user3);
```

result:

```
"user3name{↔}"
```

and it works. I have no idea why indexing is not working

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone can help with the information provided, as we're missing a lot of context. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) thoroughly, and then using the `edit` link under your under your question to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) object item order is not guranteed when you reference it:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
// order is not guaranteed
```

- first of all please note that its **undefined** not **unindefined**
- you may want to use firestore instead of realtime database .

Standard method to get document in firestore:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF").get().then( //Promise resolve );
```

Method to get docu by id :

```
gettedItem = db.collection('books').doc('fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get() //you know how ids are
```

from the previous variable gettedItem if it has a list lets say "heights" which is an array then you might need this:

```
gettedItem.then(function(doc) {
 if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data().heights[0]);
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data().heights[1]);
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data().heights[2]);
//AND SO ON...

 } else {
    alert('err sorry')
 }
})
```

Comment: Thanks the MDN link helped me a ton, that's what I probably needed the whole time